# Antd Multi-Select Options, but remove entries from search field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, multi-select

I'm using Ant Design's Select functionality. Especially multiple selections.

I would like to keep my selections intact, but I want to get rid of the entries in the search field.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Vad.jpg

In the image, I want to highlight the selections in the dropdown, but get rid of the entries highlighted in red.

Here's the code I used.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-glade-eunf6?file=/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select, Radio } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`Selected: ${value}`);
}

class SelectSizesDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    size: "default"
  };

  handleSizeChange = e => {
    this.setState({ size: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { size } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Select
          mode="multiple"
          size={size}
          placeholder="Please select"
          onChange={handleChange}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
          {children}
        </Select>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SelectSizesDemo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

I tried setting value={[ ]} inside the Select tag, but it wiped the selections as well.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the style simply :

```
<Select
    mode="multiple"
    size={size}
    className="dont-show" // <--- apply class to provide style only specific to this select
    placeholder="Please select"
    onChange={handleChange}
    style={{ width: "100%" }}
>
    {children}
</Select>

.dont-show .ant-select-selection-item {
  display: none !important;
}
```

WORKING DEMO :

[image: Edit peaceful-wescoff-yvxs1]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!. Just one more clarification. What if I wanted to show the placeholder, instead of the field being empty? Will that be possible?

Comment: there is place holder field you can use that one

Comment: I meant, with your changes, when I select items in the dropdown, the field is wiped out completely. While items are selected, can I make the "Please select" visible in the field?

Comment: That's is not as easy as this one, you need to do lots of custom changes for that.

Comment: What kind of custom changes? Could you point me in the right direction or give a general idea so that I can explore?

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps to accomplish this.

step1: add maxTagCount={0} and maxTagPlaceholder={() => 'intended placeholder name'}

```
<Select 
     mode='multiple'
     maxTagCount={0}
     maxTagPlaceholder={() => 'intended placeholder name'}
     placeholder={'intended placeholder name'}
     options={Options}
 />
```

Step2: still the placeholder text looks like it is inside a tag, we can add the following css

```
.ant-select-selection-item{
    background-color: inherit !important;
}
```